# Iterate "Task<IEnumerable<T>>" in c#?

Tags: c#, cassandra, scylla

I am playing with Scylla db and working with C# for the first time in 15 years.

After reading about Scylla and C# for few days I got below code. In the below code, I connect to the scylla cluster and try to query a table to get data from it.

```
public static async void test()
{
    var cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoints("test-endpoint").WithQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().SetConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LocalQuorum)).Build();
    var session = cluster.Connect("processks");
    var mapper = new Mapper(session);

    var cql = Cql.New("SELECT * FROM test LIMIT 10");
    var fetchResult = await mapper.FetchAsync<User>(cql).ConfigureAwait(false);
    // this just prints the object which is not what I want
    Console.WriteLine(fetchResult);
}
```

Below is my `User` class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Cassandra.Mapping;
using Cassandra.Mapping.Attributes;

namespace Test.Objects.POCO.Scylla
{
    [TableName("test")]
    [PrimaryKey("client_id")]
    public class User
    {
        [Column("client_id")]
        public int ClientId { get; set; }

        [Column("md")]
        public string MD { get; set; }

        [Column("process_ids")]
        public List<int> ProcessIds { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I iterate `fetchResult` object to print out the data I got back after executing the above query?

This is the code [link](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/master/src/Cassandra/Mapping/Mapper.cs#L82)  of `Mapper` class where `FetchAsync` method is defined and it returns `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` object back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var fetchResult = await mapper.FetchAsync<User>(cql).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

`fetchResult` will be a `IEnumerable<User>` so it's up to you to iterate over the `IEnumerable` however you want to and print the underlying `User` objects with whatever method you prefer.

`Console.WriteLine` prints the result of the provided object's `ToString()` method and neither the returned `IEnumerable` object nor the contained `User` objects have the default implementation that you're looking for.

You can implement `ToString()` on the `User` class and do something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, fetchResult));
```

Or you can just use a JSON library to convert the user object to a JSON string instead of overriding `ToString()`:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(
    Environment.NewLine, 
    fetchResult.Select(user => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user))))
```

**[EDIT]** you might be interested in our examples and docs:

https://www.datastax.com/examples (you can filter by C# language)

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.14/features/components/mapper/